# VBA Code: Insert image to cell based on url entered in form

Tags: excel, vba

I have coded a form for entering product information that allows the user to browse for a file location and inserts that location into a cell on the sheet once submitted.  I would like to code the from so that the a later cell displays the image file.  I found a fantastic resource that has code that does what I want. The resource is located at the following link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/convert-image-url-to-actual-image-in-excel/m-p/309020

The problem is that once the code is ran, it updates all the links on a sheet, creating duplicate images that are stacked.  I would like to alter and add the code to my form code so that only the new image url is added once the form is submitted.

Here is the code found at the link above:

```
Sub URLPictureInsert()
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161116
'Update #1 by Haytham Amairah in 20180104
'Update #2 by Haytham Amairah in 20180108

    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A140")
    For Each cell In Rng
        filenam = cell
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
        Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
        Pshp.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
        xCol = cell.Column + 1
        Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
        With Pshp
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 60
           .Height = 30
            .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
            .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
        End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("A2").Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here is the section of code I currently have that I would like to add the above code to:

```
Dim ComputerId As String
ComputerId = Environ$("ComputerName")
Dim Specs_Number As String
Specs_Number = Left(Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value, Application.Find(" - ", Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value) - 1)
Dim Specs_Name As String
Specs_Name = Right(Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value, (Len(Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value) - 2) - Application.Find(" - ", Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value))
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("FormData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Select Case Me.ComboBoxDivision
Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")

Case "DIVISION 23 - HEATING VENTILATING AND AIR CONDITIONING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-23")


LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value

Unload Product_Information_Form
Start_Form.Show

End Sub
```

And here is an example of what I would like (bottom half of code, the "ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = URLPictureInsert()" line of code):

```
Dim ComputerId As String
ComputerId = Environ$("ComputerName")
Dim Specs_Number As String
Specs_Number = Left(Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value, Application.Find(" - ", Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value) - 1)
Dim Specs_Name As String
Specs_Name = Right(Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value, (Len(Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value) - 2) - Application.Find(" - ", Me.ComboBoxSpecification.Value))
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("FormData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Select Case Me.ComboBoxDivision
Case "DIVISION 22 - PLUMBING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-22")

Case "DIVISION 23 - HEATING VENTILATING AND AIR CONDITIONING"
Set ws = Sheets("Div-23")

LastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
ws.Range("b" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Number
ws.Range("c" & LastRow).Value = Specs_Name
AddLink ws.Range("i" & LastRow), Me.TextBoxPicture_File_Link.Value
ws.Range("o" & LastRow).Value = Me.TextBoxSales_Rep_Email.Value


ws.Range("r" & LastRow).Value = URLPictureInsert()


Unload Product_Information_Form
Start_Form.Show

End Sub

Sub URLPictureInsert()

    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("J2:J140")
    For Each cell In Rng
        filenam = cell
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
        Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
        Pshp.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab
        xCol = cell.Column + 1
        Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
        With Pshp
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 60
            .Height = 60
            .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 3
            .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 3
        End With
lab:
    Set Pshp = Nothing
    Range("J2").Select
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. If possible, please explain in a clear and detailed way since I am still very much a novice at VBA coding and a beginner at coding in general.

Comment: It's not really reasonable to give us a dump of a whole lot of code plus a link to some other code you don't fully understand, then ask us to integrate the two and explain how we did it in a "clear and detailed way".  The first block of code is obviously looping over a range of cells, but you only need it to operate on one row, so try to make that change first.

Comment: That is a fair point, I'm hoping that at least someone ca direct me since I've spent hours trying to get this to work.

Comment: I deleted out some of the redundant code to hopefully make it easier to read.  I wanted to keep the code mostly together so that I didn't miss something that might be important.  Let me know if there is more code I could remove to streamline the post for easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demo of calling a sub to insert a picture from a given URL at a specific location.

You can call `URLPictureInsert` from your code and pass it the cell with the URL and the cell where the image should go.

```
Sub Tester()
    'get an image URL from A3 and put the image at C3
    URLPictureInsert Range("a3"), Range("C3")

End Sub



Sub URLPictureInsert(rngURL As Range, rngWhere As Range)

    Dim shp As Shape

    On Error Resume Next

    Set shp = rngWhere.Parent.Shapes.AddPicture(rngURL.Value, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
              SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=rngWhere.Left, Top:=rngWhere.Top, _
              Width:=-1, Height:=-1)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        shp.Width = 30
        shp.Height = 30
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try this.